# Can I Access a calling function's name programmatically?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, directx-9

I'm hoping to add a little functionality to a Log File system for a project I'm working on.  For my `LogError()` calls, I would like to include the function the error occurred in.  I'm wondering if there's a way that I can access the name of the function that called `LogError()` so I can programmatically access that information to add it to the log.

For example:

```
bool Engine::GraphicsManager::Initialize(const HWND i_hWindow_main)
{
    if ( !InitializeWindow( i_hWindow_main ) )
    {
        Engine::LogManager::Instance().LogError(L"GraphicsManager::Initialize - Unable to initialize graphics window");
        return false;
    }
    Engine::LogManager::Instance().LogMessage(L"Graphics window initialized successfully");

    /* SNIP */

    initialized = true;
    return true;
}
```

In the above example, I'd like `LogError()` to be able to determine that it was called from `GraphicsManager::Initialize()` and output (at least part of) that function's name instead of putting that in everywhere by hand.

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned that my `LogError()` function (and the other logging functions) are essentially wrappers for `vfwprintf_s()` so they can take variable length argument lists.  While I like the "use a macro" suggestions, I'm not sure how to tackle that potential issue (which is likely another question).

Is this *still* reasonable/possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an argument for the function name, and pass in the `__FUNCTION__` macro: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

And you could also define a macro that will automatically replace `...log...()` with `...log...(__FUNCTION__)`.

Comment: Updated my original post to say that I need to handle variable length argument lists.  I'm not terribly familiar with using macros for more complex tasks.  Can this still be done with the additional caveat?

Comment: @chaosTechnician: if I didn't miss anything, you can simply pass the function name argument before the formatting arguments. Personally, I pass an argument for each bit of useful information (line number, file name), as well as a message argument. The logging is then responsible for formatting everything.

Answer (score 1):

These are predefined macros and part of the C/C++ standard which you can use:

```
__FILE__ __LINE__
```

They are explained [here](http://www.decompile.com/cpp/faq/file_and_line_error_string.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Make a Logging macro

EDIT: Some fixes to deal with wide characters

```
//support macros
#define WIDEN2(x) L ## x
#define WIDEN(x) WIDEN2(x)
#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define __WFILE__ WIDEN(__FILE__)
#define __WFUNCTION__ WIDEN(__FUNCTION__)
#define __WLINE__ WIDEN( STRINGIZE(__LINE__) )
// logging macro
#define LOG(msg) Engine::LogManager::Instance().LogError(__WFILE__ L"::" __WFUNCTION__ L":" __WLINE__ L" - " msg)
```

Use it like this

```
if( error ) { LOG(L"Error!"); }
```

logs

```
File.cpp::Function:Line - Error!
```

This works by using C-style string concatenation. "aa" "bb" -> "aabb" along with some operator pasting to put `L` before `"astring"`. It uses the __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, and __LINE__ macros to report where the error was logged from. __LINE__ is translated into a string with the `STRINGIZE` macro. Due to crappy compliance with the standard, `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE` is recommended if you plan on using boost anyway.